# How to tell jQuery a content editable div has been updated

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable

I want to use jQuery to select an item that has been added to an HTML5 content editable div. It doesn't work right now because the item wasn't present when the page was loaded. **How do I tell jQuery that the div has been updated?**

Please see this jsfiddle for test code: http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/sjHYQ/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

<!-- This wont work on an image dragged into the div after page load -->
$('#editor img').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();
});

});​
```

I have seen other questions about this, but none seem to apply to a content editable div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#editor').on('click', 'img', function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sjHYQ/1/)**

Since you're essentially binding a dynamic element, you need to use `.on()` to delegate the click event on the `#editor` element because there is no image within the editor div when the page is loaded.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for. Also appreciate the quick explanation of .on()

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [.on() JQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event to element dynamically created

Here is an example (I use body as main container, but you need to be more specific) :

```
$("#editor").on({
    click: function (event) {    
        console.log('test')
       $(this).fadeOut();
    }
    },
    "img"
);
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sjHYQ/2/