# How to use jquery to prevent a editable div reach over our restricting length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable, maxlength

Let's said I have the following code:

```html
<div id="editing" contenteditable onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">Put text here...</div>
```

In this case, I want to restrict my user, for example, can only put 200 characters in it (including space), how can I restrict it? I know I might achieve it with jquery but most example on webs checks it when they click a button, and as I redesign my code with [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459928/how-to-tell-jquery-a-content-editable-div-has-been-updated) as base, it checks it when the div is clicked but with that in mind you can't alert user when the types over 200 words.

#### So how can I continuously checking words user type in a contenteditable div and alert them when they reach the limit?

Comment: Typically, you bind a keydown listener to the div and validate the inputs

Comment: use on input event

Comment: @Vj- I have tried the following [code](https://jsfiddle.net/yz5yyj2c/) but as a result when user types to the 21 letter it cause to stopped, restrict to 20 letters but then the 21 letter will be inputted, if you tried it yourself you'll find out when you reach limit it'll stays at 21 letter instead of 20 letter which meant if user wants to minus a letter it'll get an alert too since backspace is also a key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is simple pure js solution: if anything is there please comment i will update my answer.. :D

```js
function check()
{
 // get the HTML value.
  var content = document.getElementById('editing').innerHTML;
  //Edit : replace spaces from content (ideally you have to figure out how to remove the posible html tags that user might enter)
  content = content.replace(/&nbsp;/g," ");
  console.log(content);
 // validate value againts limit say 10 or any constant value.
 if(content.length > 20)
  {
    // alert user.
    alert('limit reached');
    // flush extra characters from end.
    document.getElementById('editing').innerHTML = content.slice(0,content.length-1);
    return;
  }
}


//Edit : if you want remove placeholder from annoying user you can flush it when user gets the focus on it say 

function checkPlaceholder()
{
  document.getElementById('editing').innerHTML = ""; 
}
```

```html
<div id="editing" contenteditable onInput="check();" onfocus="checkPlaceholder();">Put text here...</div>
```

Comment: I recommend stop it from removing the content when you reach the limit, this would be annoying for the user to have start typing all over again if they are unaware of the limit - especially seeing as the asker said 200 characters

Comment: @Booligoosh i guess though but in that case the user still can go on entering characters and the asker has to apply something to prevent submitting form unless user remove extra chars and all..

Answer (score 3):

The input event is supported with contenteditable, then just stop the event if there is too much text like so:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('editing');
var max = 20;
el.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  if (el.innerHTML.length > max) {
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.substr(0, max); // just in case
    alert('Not allowed more than ' + max + ' characters');
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="editing" contenteditable onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">Put text here...</div>
```

However, just stay away from contenteditable events. they are bad

Comment: Sir, I like your function, it's good, however I'm asking to stop not overwrites

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="editing" contenteditable onkeypress = "if($(this).text().length >= 200) {return false; }"onclick="alert(document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">Put text here...</div>
```

You `return false` `onkeypress` when the character count is greater than or equal to 200

Answer (score -1):

```
// Detect when you add a character to the div.
$('div#editing').on('keydown',function(e) {
    // Check if you already have 200 characters (but allow 'backspace' and 'del' keys).
    if (e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 46 && $(this).text().length >= 200) {
        alert('The field is limited to 200 characters');
        return false; // This will make the new character to be ignored.
    }
});
```

Comment: Sir, you should test your function since I found out it'll be quite hard when user wants to delete text after they reach the limit

Comment: Please include an explanation, and don't just dump code.

Comment: @Munucial You're right. It was so small that I thought it explained by itself, but it depends on who's reading it. I've added comments. Thanks.